# Angularjs set style for ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

im trying to set the style for a div i create in my angularjs code. I can set the class but I cant set the style. I have tried just using style tag and that didn't work either. I have

```
$scope.myHTML='<div style="left:300px;" class="squareButton"><h1>SomeText</h1></div>';
```

I've tried other things in the style tag but nothing works. It will work if i put it in the css file. is there a way i can do it in the style=""? i need to make multiple divs with different positions. so i can't just use the css. how do i get the style tag to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any errors in the Web Developer Console? Or did you trusted the HTML with `$sce`?

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(...)
}
```

Comment: so i tried using $sce.trustAsHtml and i get the same thing when i look at the html when page is loaded i it shows <div class="squareButton">...</div>. nothing about style="". anything else i should try?

Comment: That's weird. Do you have JS Fiddle?

Comment: nvm i must have been doing something wrong. i was making a div with divs in it so its was only 1 string i was return for ng bind html. what i was doing was trusting as html the div i was adding to the string. i changed it so i just trust as html when the string it fully complete.

Answer (score 0):

Use [textAngular](https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular) that is more flexible than ngSanitize.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29758749/751392