# Angular.js sanitizer removes name attribute from anchor

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm binding some html part with `ng-bind-html=html`. Problem is with anchors with name attribute `$scope.html = '<a name="test">Test</a>'` because (I guess) `ngSanitize` removes name attribute. After that in-page link to anchor does not work.

Is it possible to tell sanitizer to leave anchors' name attribute?

Comment: it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845061/allow-certain-style-attributes-with-ngsanitize

Comment: unfortunatelly it's not...

Answer (score 0):

this may help you , use this

```
$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml('<a name="test">Test</a>');
```

add `$sce` to your controller

Comment: Well it's not a solution, because `html` may be external page I don't trust so easy. I want sanitization in general. I have problem only with this one attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<div ng-bind-html="to_trusted(html)"></div>
```

And add this function to your controller:

```
$scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
}
```

Don't forget add `$sce` to your controller's initialization.